# Migrate openldap to AzureAD

Tags: active-directory, azure

I come from pure AWS world and exploring Azure to migrate resources. I have an openldap server on a linux VM in AWS serving our web application. 
I'm planning to migrate it to Azure AD to utilize the SSO ability to some of our applications.

Is there a way to export the ldif from oprnldap and import it to AD? Apparently AD connect on Azure only support windows servers.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to do this directly as an export, but it could perhaps with a few inbetween steps.

One way would be to talk LDAP with the Azure AD, this is possible through [Azure AD Domain Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/). It does however cost something to use this service in Azure so it is not free.

Another way would be to take your LDIF output, then format it to something more object friendly like a .csv file or json or something else with structure so you could load it into Powershell and and use a Powershell script to create the users from the LDIF source. But again you would need to structure your LDIF so it makes sense when you import it in Powershell.